# Offline Knowledge Based Article Creator

Tags: offline, knowledge-base

Is there a offline application that allows you to create coding tutorials (with code syntax styling)? I am trying to find an application that will allow you to export the document to PDF. Preferably this application will also be able to run on OS X.

Is there anything out there for this?

Comment: Can't you create it as one may normally in an editor, then "print" to a pdf file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an editor with syntax highlighting that allows export of RTF, export the colorized text, and import that into your document editing program.

For OS you can use e.g. [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and install the [SublimeHighLight package](https://github.com/n1k0/SublimeHighlight).
But if you search around for [os x editor syntax highlighting](https://www.google.com/search?q=os+x+editor+syntax+highlighting) and then for the found editors search their name + *rtf output* or *export rtf* for  you may come across other candidates.

For Windows such an editor is [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Then [use an additional style like in this Word example](https://superuser.com/questions/419814/create-a-microsoft-word-quick-style-for-a-code-snippet-box) to color the background or maybe change the font. I think Word is no longer much used in the Mac world, but you can do this in practically any document processor.

From there printing to PDF should be easy. I'm not a Mac man, in Windows one could use [PDF995](http://www.pdf995.com/).

For details about how others solved this in Windows see e.g. [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/how-do-you-display-code-snippets-in-ms-word-preserving-format-and-syntax-highlig).